# Find the number of the element of this set.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

This is the question that someone give me.

Let the set, $S = \{ n | p \leq  3^{-n}q \lt 243p\}$ for a integer, $n$ and the positive real numbers $p,q$

Find the number of the element the set,$ S$

---

I thought the answer is countable infinity. But the someone who gavemethis questio  said the answer is 4. 
It looks like the above question weird I thought.

To conclude the answer is 4, Do we need more condition, don't we?

What do you think?

Any opinion would be help. Thanks.

Comment: Could you give a bit more information about $p$ and $q$? Because if we pick $p=2$ and $q=1$ then the number of elements in $S$ is $0$. Or are we looking for the maximum number of elements $S$ can have for given $p$ and $q$. If $S$ is of the form $$S=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:\exists p,q\in\mathbb{N}\text{ such that }p\leq3^{-n}q<243p\},$$ then I agree with you and the answer should be countably infinite.

Comment: Also, important to note that $3^{4}=243$ so if for fixed $p$ and $q$ the answer is at most $4$ and $4$ if and only if $p=q$.

Comment: There are no more information $p$ and $q$. Might be the question is odd and uncorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that $|S|=5$ in all cases. Note that unlike what's been written in the comments, $3^4=81; 3^5=243$.

Contrary to often used naming convention, as stated $n$ can be any integer, not just a natural number.

The left part of the inequality for $n$ can be equivalently transformed as follows, considering that $p$ and $q$ are assumed to be positive:

$$
\begin{eqnarray} 
p                  & \le & 3^{-n}q  &\Longleftrightarrow& \\
\frac{p}q          & \le & 3^{-n}   &\Longleftrightarrow& \\
\log_3\frac{p}q    & \le & -n       &\Longleftrightarrow& \\
n                  & \le & -\log_3\frac{p}q.     \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

The same can be done for the right part of the inequality (I leave out the equivalent steps as done above):

$$
\begin{eqnarray} 
3^{-n}q    & < &  243p               &\Longleftrightarrow& \\
n          & > & -\log_3\frac{243p}q &\Longleftrightarrow& \\
n          & > & -\log_3\frac{p}q - \log_3 243 &\Longleftrightarrow& \\
n          & > & -\log_3\frac{p}q - 5. \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

So we find that the condition given in the definition of $S$ is equivalent to

$$ -\log_3\frac{p}q - 5 < n \le -\log_3\frac{p}q$$

No matter what exact value $\log_3\frac{p}q$ has, there are always exactly 5 integer values of $n$ that fullfill the above condition:

$$\lfloor-\log_3\frac{p}q\rfloor -k$$

for $k=0,1,2,3,4$.